# Read variable from URL path

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing

I'm trying to read a variable from the URL in Angular.

I have this in my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':page', component: BlogComponent}
];
```

and this in my blog components constructor.

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  const page = params.params.page;
  cacheService
    .getAllPostIds()
    .subscribe(postIds => this.loadPage(cacheService, postIds, page)
  );
});
```

This works if there is a paramater, ie `www.url.com/1` returns page = 1.

If there is nothing after the url (just `www.url.com`), this however **never** triggers the route subscription. Is this the proper way to subscribe to url variables and changes, if not how should I do it, if it is, how do I make it work even if with just a blank url `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with 2 routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BlogComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: ':page', component: BlogComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

and a constructor like this:

```
constructor(private cacheService: CacheService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    let page = params.params.page;
    if (page == null){
      page = 1;
    }
    console.log('page: ' + page);
    cacheService
      .getAllPostIds()
      .subscribe(postIds => this.loadPage(cacheService, postIds, params.params.page)
    );
  });
}
```

The original path was not getting hit when there was no paramater for `:page`, and then added so that the constructor defaults to 1 if there is no page.

Not sure if this is the best way though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bellow code to fetch route parameters reactively.

```
constructor ( private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {

this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params) => {
        this.page = params[‘page’];
    }
  );
}
```